# Query to fetch records from a table, for a particular date if the date column is in date data type

Tags: sql, db2

Query to fetch records from a table, for a particular date if the date column is in DATE data type.
Iam working in DB2.
if i give data format in 03/06/2011(mm/dd/YYYY)

ex:
Select * from table customer where date = "03/06/2011" is not working. date column is DATE data type.

Comment: Please be more descriptive, show what you have tried so far, and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Change double quotes to single quotes, maybe?

```
Select * from table customer where date = '03/06/2011'
```

Also, using ISO format to specify a date value might be more reliable:

```
Select * from table customer where date = '2011-03-06'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert your string date to an actual Date, like this:

```
Select * from table customer where date = DATE('03/06/2011');
```